# How do I check if my UML deployment diagram is UML compliant?

Tags: deployment, uml, diagram, deployment-diagram

I have a UML deployment diagram for a certification test that requires it be UML compliant.
The UML tool I used for creating my deployment diagram did not have 3D rectangles I could use for a application server in my diagram, so I used a "flat (2D)" rectangle to represent my app server.
Should I be alright using a flat rectangle as my app server?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of visual layout yes, you're fine with a 2D rectangle because the UML specifications does not in fact specify these layouts and if you read the spec you'll see they've used very basic drawing tools there.

However, in order to ensure your diagram is UML compliant you do need a fully-featured UML tool. A simple drawing tool, such as MS Visio, won't cut it. There's a good list of UML tools on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).